# Evaluate iterated integral by changing to polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

$$\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx$$

$x^2+y^2=r^2$

$$\int\int_0 r^3\cos\theta \sin\theta|r|\,dr\,d\theta$$
I don't know what $r =$ at line $x = 1/2$. I don't know value of $\theta$. Help me evaluate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The region of integration represented by D can be expressed as $D= D_1 \ U \ D_2$ where $$D_1 = \{ (r, \theta)| 0 \le r \le 1, {\pi\over 3} \le \theta \le {\pi\over 2} \}$$ and $$D_2 = \{ (r, \theta) | 0 \le \theta \le {\pi\over 3}, 0 \le r \le {1\over {2cos \theta}} \}$$ Then you can split the double integral over the two non - intersecting domains and compute the required integral.

Comment: So I split my integral in two and add?

Comment: You should probably explain where you got those from. It doesn't help anyone learn how to approach this question if they are just told what the region is in terms of a different coordinate system, you need to show the method.

Comment: OK but I came to know this from the sketch of the region of integration itself.

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of question its good to sketch the region.

We have $0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$, and $0 \leq x \leq 1/2$.

The first chain of inequalities can be re-written as $y\geq 0, y^2 \leq 1 - x^2$ or $1 \geq y^2 + x^2$, $y\geq 0$. This is the upper-half unit disk. Then we have the vertical strip between $0$ and $1/2$ for $x$.

Try to draw a picture of this. You'll see that the region lies in the first quadrant. This gives you a range for $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$. Then, you have to find an expression for the $r$ that works for $\theta$, in terms of $\theta$.

Wolfram gives this sketch: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+0+%3C+x+%3C+1%2F2%2C+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%3C+1%2C+y%3E0

Alternatively, you can try to find $\theta$ in terms of $r$. Again, try to find the range of values that $r$ varies between (you may be able to read it off the diagram, or, you could re-write the inequalities above in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.) Then for each value of $r$, work out the range of $\theta$ that lies within the region.

Comment: Thanks. My sketch looks like that. I see r is 0 to 1.

Comment: This is not correct. Note that if the region is $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ and $0\leq r \leq 1$ then you get the whole upper-half circle.

Comment: This is because $r \in [0,1]$ does not work for *every* $\theta$, only for *some* $\theta$.

Comment: $\theta$ is pi/4 to pi/2.

Comment: well, again, you need to express $\theta$ *in terms of $r$*. This will be tricky, because the region has is not nice and smooth around the edge.

Answer (score 0):

$R \in [0,1]$ because the radious isn't affected by the change of coordinates but you should take some care about $\theta$.

When $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$, then $y=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ then $\theta=tan^-1(\sqrt{3})=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ so $\theta \in [0, \dfrac{\pi}{3}]$

Comment: None of the region of integration lies below the $y$-axis, consequently, $\theta$ should lie between $0$ and $\pi$.

Comment: Oh it's true, I will correct it. My mistake.

Comment: How you get y = $\sqrt{3}/2$? How you know θ=tan−1(√3)?

Comment: $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ so you plug $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ on it. And $tan(\theta)=\dfrac{y}{x}$ then $\theta=tan^{-1}(\dfrac{y}{x})$